# Extending Laravel Router API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to extend the Laravel 5.6 router class to add some handy methods to register routes.

I have created a class that extends the `Illuminate\Routing\Router` class like this:

```
Namespace App\Overrides;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router as LaravelRouter;

class Router extends LaravelRouter
{

    public function apiReadResource($name, $controller, array $options = [])
    {
        $this->resource($name, $controller, array_merge([
            'only' => ['index', 'show'],
        ], $options));
    }

    public function apiWriteResource($name, $controller, array $options = [])
    {
        $this->resource($name, $controller, array_merge([
            'except' => ['index', 'show', 'edit', 'create', 'destroy'],
        ], $options));
    }

    public function apiRelationshipResources($name, $controller, array $relationships, array $options = [])
    {
        foreach($relationships as $relationship)
        {
            $this->get(
                $name.'/{id}/'.$relationship,
                [
                    'uses' => $controller . '@' . $relationship,
                    'as'   => $name . '.' . $relationship,
                ]
            );
        }
    }

}
```

I have registered my extended class like this in the default `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use App\Overrides\Router as APIRouter;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';


    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('router', function ($app) {
            return new APIRouter($app['events'], $app);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    [more code...]
}
```

In the routes file I call my own custom methods like this: `Route::apiWriteResource('users', 'UserController');` or like this `Route::apiRelationshipResources('users', 'UserController', ['reviews']);`

All routes are registered and show up correctly in `php artisan route:list`, but none of the routes actually work. They all gives the standard 404 page.

What am I doing wrong? What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on documentation from [here](https://tighten.co/blog/the-magic-of-laravel-macros), [here](https://blog.nasrulhazim.com/2017/12/laravel-route-macro/), [here](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-route-tips-to-improve-your-routing) and checking in [Router.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1214) I came to idea to write an answer.

Try following steps:

1) Create **Routing** folder inside of **app** folder

Create a **macros**:

2) **app\Routing\ApiReadResource.php** with such content:

```
<?php
namespace App\Routing

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;


class ApiReadResource
{
    public static function register()
    {
        if (!Router::hasMacro('apiReadResource')) {
            Router::macro('apiReadResource', function ($name, $controller, $options = []) {
                Router::resource(
                   $name, 
                   $controller, 
                   array_merge(['only' => ['index', 'show']], $options)
                );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

3) **app\Routing\ApiWriteResource.php** with such content:

```
<?php
namespace App\Routing

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;


class ApiWriteResource
{
    public static function register()
    {
        if (!Router::hasMacro('apiWriteResource')) {
            Router::macro('apiWriteResource', function ($name, $controller, $options = []) {
                Router::resource(
                   $name, 
                   $controller, 
                   array_merge(['except' => ['index', 'show', 'edit', 'create', 'destroy']], $options)
                );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

4) **app\Routing\ApiRelationshipResources.php** with such content:

```
<?php
namespace App\Routing

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;


class ApiRelationshipResources
{
    public static function register()
    {
        if (!Router::hasMacro('apiRelationshipResources')) {
            Router::macro('apiRelationshipResources', function ($name, $controller, array $relationships, $options = []) {
              foreach($relationships AS $relationship) {
                Router::get(
                   $name.'/{id}/'.$relationship,
                   array_merge($options, [
                     'uses' => $controller . '@' . $relationship,
                     'as'   => $name . '.' . $relationship,
                   ])
                );
              }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

5) Register them inside **AppServiceProvider**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

    }
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        \App\Routing\ApiReadResource::register();
        \App\Routing\ApiWriteResource::register();
        \App\Routing\ApiRelationshipResources::register();
    }
}
```

Comment: Macros seams a very useful feature that I didn't know about. I will try this tonight. It's almost worth the bounty for just teaching me about this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pelmered glad to be helpful. Feel free to fix my answer if I forgot something (:

Comment: I found it a bit unnecessary to create one class per macro so I combined them into one class. But otherwise I went for this solution. It worked great! Thanks!

Comment: You missed an opening square bracket in the ApiWriteResource example in the array_merge, but otherwise the code was working perfectly.